# Yii2 populateRelation() fills data, but data is not saved

Tags: yii, yii2, augmented-reality

This is a model Method

```
public function setTerritories($territories)
{
    $t = Territory::find()->where(['id' => $territories])->all();

    $this->populateRelation('territories', $t);     
}
```

The controller is simple

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->scenario = 'update';

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The relation is filled; if I `var_dump($model->territories);` it shows needed models, but after save they're not attached.

Why doesn't `populateRelation` save the data?

Comment: The question is `why populateRelation() don't save your related data`?

Comment: Yes, I suppouse it should, but it doesnt work.Also if Im mistake and it should NOT, I want to know does AR can link many relations at once?

Comment: So answer is - no. `populateRelation()` is not saving related data, to link relations you should use [`link()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail) method. More in [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#saving-relations)

Comment: So the one way to save many is necessity of using loop ? foreach() link()

Comment: For now - using only Yii2 assets - yes. But there's an third party solution: [Yii2 - linkAll()](https://github.com/cornernote/yii2-linkall).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is totally answers my question. Dont you know then what cases needed to use populateRelations approach ?

Comment: Yii2 core uses this method, you can find usages in `/vendor` folder ;)

Comment: Thanks, bro. All questions closed !